# How to scrape "span typeof" or "span property" data using Python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the address, but unable to do this.

I want the address as: `Airedale General Hospital, Skipton Road, Steeton , Keighley, West Yorkshire, BD20 6TD`

Can anyone help me out with the below:

```
                    <p>                       
                      </span>
                      <span typeof="PostalAddress">
                        <span property="streetAddress">Airedale General Hospital, Skipton Road, Steeton</span>
                        , <span property="addressLocality">Keighley</span>, <span property="addressRegion">West Yorkshire</span>, <span property="postalCode">BD20 6TD</span>
                      </span>
                      <br>
                    </p>
```

I tried with the below code but not working:

```
p_address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p[PostalAddress]').get_attribute()
print(p_address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this line to get address:

```
p_address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[typeof="PostalAddress"]').text
```